in-place change is not working, unable to add a new column by converting another str column to datetime using `str.strptime`
In the demo code below I want to add a new column to a dataframe which converts another column from str to datetime with the specified format.
However, based on the output, nothing has changed. No new column as a result of the conversion is added that is of the datetime type.
Why the in-place change to the original dataframe is not working?
Code:
data = {
    'Timestamp': [
        "4/7/2024 18:42:10",
        "4/7/2024 18:42:11",
        "4/7/2024 18:42:12"
    ],
    'Date': [
        "3/19/2024",
        "3/19/2024",
        "3/19/2024"
    ],
    'Amount': [
        "1292.23",
        "543.95",
        "679.82"
    ]
}

df = pl.from_dict(data)
print(df, '\n')

df.with_columns(
    pl.col('Timestamp')
      .str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
      .alias('dt_f')
)

print(df)

Output
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────────────┬───────────┬─────────┐
│ Timestamp         ┆ Date      ┆ Amount  │
│ ---               ┆ ---       ┆ ---     │
│ str               ┆ str       ┆ str     │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════╪═════════╡
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:10 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 1292.23 │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:11 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 543.95  │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:12 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 679.82  │
└───────────────────┴───────────┴─────────┘ 

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────────────┬───────────┬─────────┐
│ Timestamp         ┆ Date      ┆ Amount  │
│ ---               ┆ ---       ┆ ---     │
│ str               ┆ str       ┆ str     │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════╪═════════╡
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:10 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 1292.23 │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:11 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 543.95  │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:12 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 679.82  │
└───────────────────┴───────────┴─────────┘

Assigning to a new dataframe works:
df_formated = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('Timestamp')
      .str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
      .alias('dt_f')
)

print(df_formated)

Output of the new dataframe
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────────────────┬───────────┬─────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Timestamp         ┆ Date      ┆ Amount  ┆ dt_f                │
│ ---               ┆ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---                 │
│ str               ┆ str       ┆ str     ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:10 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 1292.23 ┆ 2024-04-07 18:42:10 │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:11 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 543.95  ┆ 2024-04-07 18:42:11 │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:12 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 679.82  ┆ 2024-04-07 18:42:12 │
└───────────────────┴───────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────┘


with_columns always returns a DataFrame. Please note that Creating a new DataFrame using this method does not create a new copy of existing data

@user459872, thanks. What I learned: the DataFrame returned by with_columns is just a view of the transformation, and the data within the original dataframe is not changed at all, no matter wether the transformation is replacing existing columns or creating new columns. If I want to keep the DataFrame associated with this view I need to assign it to a new variable.

not sure I'd call it a "view" - it's just a new dataframe, and the original one isn't modified. if you want to keep the new dataframe around, you need to assign it to a variable

In your code, you used df.with_columns() to add a new column. But, because you did not assign the result of df.with_columns() back to df  the dataframe  df remains unchanged after the operation.What you need to do is the following.
import polars as pl

data = {
    'Timestamp': [
        "4/7/2024 18:42:10",
        "4/7/2024 18:42:11",
        "4/7/2024 18:42:12"
    ],
    'Date': [
        "3/19/2024",
        "3/19/2024",
        "3/19/2024"
    ],
    'Amount': [
        "1292.23",
        "543.95",
        "679.82"
    ]
}

df = pl.from_dict(data)
print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df, '\n')

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('Timestamp')
      .str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
      .alias('dt_f')
)

print("Modified DataFrame:")
print(df)


So that
Original DataFrame:
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────────────┬───────────┬─────────┐
│ Timestamp         ┆ Date      ┆ Amount  │
│ ---               ┆ ---       ┆ ---     │
│ str               ┆ str       ┆ str     │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════╪═════════╡
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:10 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 1292.23 │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:11 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 543.95  │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:12 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 679.82  │
└───────────────────┴───────────┴─────────┘ 

Modified DataFrame:
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────────────────┬───────────┬─────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Timestamp         ┆ Date      ┆ Amount  ┆ dt_f                │
│ ---               ┆ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---                 │
│ str               ┆ str       ┆ str     ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:10 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 1292.23 ┆ 2024-04-07 18:42:10 │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:11 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 543.95  ┆ 2024-04-07 18:42:11 │
│ 4/7/2024 18:42:12 ┆ 3/19/2024 ┆ 679.82  ┆ 2024-04-07 18:42:12 │
└───────────────────┴───────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────┘


